# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (6) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, openai-whisper, whisper

I am implementing multithreading on whisper Api. I getting this error `RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (6) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 3`

Can anyone help me please. I am new to this I searched but didn't get anything.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import numpy as np
def transcribe_chunk(model, file):
    # print(file)
    result = model.transcribe(file)
    print(result)
    return result["text"]

def process_audio(filename):
    transcript = open("transcript.txt", "w+")
    myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file(filename)
    chunks_length_ms = 600000
    chunks = make_chunks(myaudio, chunks_length_ms)
    print(chunks)
    model = whisper.load_model("small")

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            chunk_array = np.array(chunk.get_array_of_samples())
            audio = chunk_array.astype(np.float32)/32768.0
            print("audio", audio)
            future = executor.submit(transcribe_chunk, model, audio)
            futures.append(future)

        for future in futures:
            result = future.result()
            transcript.write(result + ".\n")

process_audio("user_story.mp3")
```